# C++ Primer 5 ed.1.23 Reading from a file stream

Tags: c++, filestream

I'm teaching myself C++ by working through C++ Primer 5th edition and I've come up to exercise 1.23 which states: Write a program that reads several transactions and counts how many transactions occur for each ISBN.

I thought about using variables to store the transaction information but in a real scenario this wouldn't be scalable. I've done some research and I've been trying to read a text file via the Fstream header.

My question is when using an fstream how would I get it to look in the text file and return how many entries there are for that particular ISBN number?

Is my thinking on the right track? Is there a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: Usually when you don't know how many of something there will be the answer has something to do with `std::vector`, but in this case you may find `std::map` more appropriate.

Comment: As referred to above, you need to be thinking in terms of data structures. In this case, a dynamic data structure to accommodate your unknown memory requirements at run time.

Comment: I’ll do research but what is the difference between a vector and a map?

Comment: `vector` is a dynamically sized list. You can keep putting stuff in until your computer runs out of memory. You look stuff up by indexing it. You ask for spot 15, and (assuming you have 15 or more items in the `vector`) you get the value at 15. `map` allow you to use something other than an index to perform look up. If you make a `map` of the ISBN to the number of times you've seen that ISBN, you're pretty much done. The counting code could be as simple as `isbncount[isbn]++;`

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using fstream is just a basic idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

std::ifstream file("file_name.txt");
std::string ISBN("99959");

if (!file)
    throw std::runtime_error("Open file error");
std::string line; // Or whatever the data is in the file
int count = 0;
while (file) 
{
     std::getline(file, line);
     if (line.find(ISBN) == std::string::npos)
         ++count;
}
```